# Fill color issue in TCPDF

Tags: php, pdf, tcpdf

Im generating PDF files with TCPDF, and im setting a BG image for the page, everything works fine except fillcolor for the cell, Im writing text on to the document with WriteHTMLCell(), all attrivutes are applying for this, except fill color

```
$pdf->SetFillColor(240,50,20);
```

If I disable the BG image then it is working, I feel fill color is on bottom layer, any help to get the fill color visible will be helpful, thank you.

Answer (score 5):

I'm assuming you're adding your background image with the `Image` method?  If so, call `setPageMark` after you add your background image.  [setPageMark Doc link](http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/code/classTCPDF.html#a15d65cdde4d6d9df6d1c7fdb985c0e22)

For example:

```
$pdf->SetFillColor(240,50,20);
$pdf->Image('curry.png', 35,35, 200);
$pdf->SetPageMark();
$pdf->WriteHTMLCell(0,40,72,72,$text,0,0,true);
```

Will let the fill color be drawn on top of the image.  You'll need to use `setPageMark` to render borders on top of `Image`'s like this as well.